# Cant order my form field in python django correctly

Tags: python, django

I try to order my form (in Django) but it doesn't work. I tried some ways but nothing helps.

I tried for example with SortedDict from `django.utils.datastructures`. But this is not up to date...

```
class RegisterForm (UserCreationForm):
    
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'name','email', 'username','password1','password2'}
        field_order = {'name','email', 'username','password1','password2'}


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.rearrange_field_order()
        
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm,self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.name = self.cleaned_data['name']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

This is the order of the output:

- Username:
- Password:
- Name:
- Password confirmation:
- Email:

Can anyone help? At least with a method that is up to date?

Comment: You're setting `fields` and `field_order` as sets... use lists instead... `field_order = ['name','email', 'username','password1','password2']` - note the `[]`'s instead of the `{}`s...

Comment: omg... rigth^^thanks that worked

Answer (score 3):

You have made `fields` and `field_order` sets. Sets are not ordered. They should be lists or tuples.

```
fields = ['name','email', 'username','password1','password2']
field_order = ['name','email', 'username','password1','password2']
```